# Apresentar items de uma lista no html do django

Tags: html, python, django

O meu código é o seguinte:

```
{% for item in saldo %}
{{item}}
{% endfor %}
```

E gostava de apresentar os números (na imagem), cada um em cada linha. Alguém sabe como? Tentei fazer um "for" dentro do for postado mas não funciona.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode postar o template dessa parte? Só pra sabermos se isso é pra ser uma lista ou tabela

Comment: já resolvi, obrigado!

Comment: Bacana! Pois compartilha aí a soluçao :P podem ter outras pessoas futuramente com um problema parecido. Publica como resposta e marca como a certa :)

Answer (score 0):

Tente trocar o código por este:

```
{% for item in saldo %}
  <div>{{item}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Nunca mexi com Django, mas imagino que isso possa resolver.

Comment: aparece na mesma todos os resultados na mesma célula. (coloquei um print na edição da pergunta)

Answer (score 0):

Tenta adicionar uma quebra de linha:

```
{{item}} <br/>
```